# How to stop an application auto starting

Tags: autostart

Thunderbird has suddenly decided to auto start each time I logon to the desktop. Xubuntu 16.04.

It is not configured to auto start in the session settings panel, where else should I be looking ?

Comment: I just bumped into this exact same thing and I had to clear something out to get it to stop.  Let me go back through my history and see if I can find what I did.

Comment: Cheers, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory serves me correct, it has to do with the state files that are stored in the `~/.cache/sessions/` folder.  Removing all those should take care of this.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*
```

If that works, you could write that into a startup script to clear that folder out each time you boot up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did the job. Cheers !

Comment: @hatterman Glad it helped you, and glad that I recently went through this.  =)

Comment: Just did a quick google on '.cache/session/' and got a stack exchange link about this very issue. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52087/clear-xfce4-session. Looks like I could also have just put the desktop into the state I want (so close all apps would be enough) then save the session on logout. Never thought of that !! Anyway, your answer did the trick.

Comment: @hatterman Ah, good find.  Nice to know about the session saving on logout.  =)