# Most windows appear offscreen

Tags: window

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Lately I've been having an issue with all the windows that had been opened appearing off screen, where I could see most of the window but the title bar including the close and maximize buttons were submerged into the upper left corner of the screen. Everytime a window is opened I needed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and then moved it to from offscreen before I could work with the application. It's really time consuming when you do this hundreds of times a day. I tried to search on google for a solution but really haven't got any working for me.

Comment: Maybe there is something stored in the cache causing the windows to try to open in other locations.  Maybe this might help?  https://askubuntu.com/a/869119/231142

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.